# What's your favorite web view for Subversion (SVN) repositories?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have just built up my first SVN server, along with the mod_dav_svn module for Apache so that I have a rudimentary web view into the repository.

There appear to be lots of alternate/additional packages to make the web view more full-featured, along the lines of what you would see at Launchpad or Sourceforge.

What's your favorite web view for SVN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some options:

- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion) It's free/open-source, and widely used. The SVN-browsing part of Trac is [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser)
- [bsSvnBrowser](https://bssvnbrowser.bountysource.com/) - an AJAX'y subversion browser ([demo](https://bssvnbrowser.bountysource.com/svn/!tree/30))
- [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/features/) - Written in PHP, looks nice ([demo](http://demo.websvn.info/))

Comment: I went with Trac, I like the bug-tracking and other additional features. I like this answer because it had three solid alternatives to pick from.

Comment: WebSVN is not maintained anymore, the current project owner has switched from SVN to something else.

Answer (score 7):

We use [ViewVC](https://github.com/viewvc/viewvc/) internally which works great for our needs.

Answer (score 5):

Much more than just a web interface to svn: [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) -- open source and includes issue tracking and a wiki.  Not the easiest thing to set up though.

Answer (score 2):

Expensive but imho the best one out there

Atlassian  FishEye

http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/

Comment: That's what I call consensus :)

Answer (score 0):

[Warehouse](http://www.warehouseapp.com/). Just went [open source](http://github.com/entp/warehouse/tree/master), too.

Comment: The Warehouse website is frustrating in that I couldn't find any system requirements.  Does this solution only work on the Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

The folks at [BeanStalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) provide both the SVN server itself and an interface to permit you to work with your repository.  While this doesn't apply if you already have an SVN server, you should check them out if you are just getting started.  Note: I am a user of the service but am otherwise unaffiliated with them.

Comment: Very nice looking SVN hosting.  Can't decide if I want to run my own server, along with all the backup and management issues, or use an online hosting service like this one...